# GCS - multiple credentials in a single boto file

Tags: google-cloud-storage, boto

New to GCS (just got started with it today). Looks very promising.

Is there anyway to use multiple S3 accounts (or GCS) in a single boto file? I only see the option to assign keys to one S3 and one GCS account in a single file. I'd like to use multiple credentials.

We're like to copy from S3 to S3, or GCS to GCS, with each of those buckets using different keys.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to setup multiple profiles within your .boto file.

You could add something like:

```
[profile prod]
gs_access_key_id=....
gs_secret_access_key=....

[profile dev]
gs_access_key_id=....
gs_secret_access_key=....
```

And then from your code you can add a profile_name= parameter to the connection call:

```
con = boto.gs.connection(profile_name="dev")
```

Comment: You could pass the profile name as an argument and pull it using the contents of sys.argv

Comment: Also take a look at the getopt module if you're not already familiar with it.   I find it can make things a little more user friendly with minimal code  - https://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html

Comment: Thank you for Mike for your responses. I'm new to Python as of three hours ago and appreciate you bearing with me.

For a simple script like this, how would I pass in the profile names?

gsutil rsync -d -r s3://my-s3-bucket gs://my-gcs-bucket

Thanks again for your patience!

Comment: I'm not sure if the gsutil command natively works between multiple profiles.  You could possibly wrap this in a bash script though and do the transfer in a few stages.  Prior to running each gsutil command you can export the environment var BOTO_CONFIG to point to a different .boto file.  It's a slightly different approach and a little less elegant but would a lot quicker to implement than tweaking the gsutil command itself.

Comment: Why is it important to have a single boto config file for all your credentials? I have many boto config files, one per credential, and I switch between them via the BOTO_CONFIG environment variable. If you define shell aliases (e.g., testenv, prodenv, etc.) it can be pretty easy to switch boto config files.

Comment: Thanks Mike S (and thank you too for your patience), it's not important at all to have a single boto config file.

I'm just new to Python and trying to figure out how to call gsutil within a python script and pass in a BOTO_CONIG variable. I've been searching but can't find a thing. 

This is how I'm currently calling: C:\Python27\python.exe gsutil rsync -r  s3://bucket1  s3://bucket2

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use multiple boto files, just make sure that the credentials in each of them are valid. Every time you need to switch between them, run the following command with the right path.

$ BOTO_CONFIG=/path/to_boto gsutil cp SOME_FILE gs://bucket

Example : 
BOTO_CONFIG=/etc/boto.cfg gsutil -m cp text.txt gs://bucket

Additionally, you can have aliases for your different profiles. Just create an alias for each command and you are set !

Comment: Thanks for the response Marius, I'm attempting to do this within the command line using rsync