# Gsutil multiple gs_service_key_file configuration in .boto

Tags: google-cloud-storage, boto, gsutil

I am using gsutil and have multiple storages and each storage has its own gs_service_key_file configuration file. I want to be able to interact with multiple storages at the same time, but in the .boto file I can specify only one credentials file:

```
gs_service_key_file = /home/gsutil_creds/gsutil_first_storage.json
```

And when I run for example this command I don't need to specify the storage:

```
gsutil rsync data gs://mybucket/data
```

Is it possible to specify all different credentials files in the .boto file and when running the command specify the profile you are using? Since currently, I can interact with only one storage until I edit .boto file to a different configuration.

Or maybe it is possible to specify the configuration file in the command when running it? Although it should let interacting with multiple storages.

Comment: Hi, can you see if [multiple credentials in a single boto file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31710088/gcs-multiple-credentials-in-a-single-boto-file) helps you?

Comment: @ZeenathSN Hi, as I understand, the profiles are created directly in the .boto file. But in the example, it is shown [profile prod] \n gs_access_key_id=.... \n gs_secret_access_key=.... Will it work also with the gs_service_key_file (path of JSON configuration file)? Also, I want to use gsutil within the command line. That being said, can I have only one .boto file and use different configuration files by using the --profile argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate them into different files and specify which one you want to use by using the `BOTO_CONFIG` environment variable for each command:

```
BOTO_CONFIG=/path/to/config gsutil rsync ....
```

For more info, see this section in the gsutil docs:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/boto-gsutil#location

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So I should make a copy of the .boto file for each of my storages and only the gs_service_key_file variable should be different?

For example, if I am sending data to storage1 (let's say it takes a long time) and then in another terminal window I start sending data to storage2 (with your command changing the .boto config file and data to storage1 still sending) - will it affect the first command? I am just wondering if setting BOTO_CONFIG variable each time won't cause any problems.

Comment: You can also make use of the BOTO_PATH variable -- that lets you provide multiple boto files to be loaded in the specified order.  That way, you can have a "base" boto config file, then an assortment of boto files that additional values to define.  When launching gsutil, this might look like `BOTO_PATH="/path/to/base.boto:/path/to/svc_key_1_cfg.boto" gsutil <...>`.  As for running two different gsutil commands at once, you'll want to specify a different state directory for each command; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56815155/how-to-change-the-location-of-gsutil-directory.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Regarding running two different gsutil commands at once, from your answer, does it mean that it is not enough to set the BOTO_CONFIG path, for example, if I want to use gsutil cp through 2 terminal windows to send data to two different buckets? Why state directory is needed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The state directory holds "locked" files for managing cached credentials. I've seen gsutil hang if multiple processes are competing to use the same credential lockfile at once.